# How to get a value from a database onto my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, apache

Hi I am struggling to figure out how to retrieve the value from querying from an oracle database onto my web page? 
I am quite new to coding and have managed to create the skeleton for where I want the code to be along with the controller and router (router not included below) to create a microservice for this action to be called. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Here are some snippits from my httpd (where I have 'Number' I want it to query the `SELECT COUNT(Customer_ID) from Book`:

```js
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>General Info 1</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Information</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td># Customers</td>
        <td>Number</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also have the following controller too:

```js
async function database_stats(query) {
  query = `SELECT COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) from BOOK`;
  return query;
}

module.exports.database_stats = database_stats;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is very vague however... willing to send you in the right direction. The Answer depends on if you are using a 'stand alone front end' or a 'server side rendered page'. In the case of a 'stand alone front end' please do some research on [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). You can make a 'AJAX' request to your server to get the data, then use javascript to inject the data into the DOM. otherwise i would suggest looking into a template language such as [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) to inject variables into your html & serve.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have created an Ajax call to just that. My issue is trying to figure out how to get that onto the HTML page (i.e. where Number currently is)

Comment: it would be wise to set a 'id' attribute on the `<td id="tableNumber"></td>` so with the HTTP response you could write (trivial) code like this ```document.getElementById(`tableNumber`).innerText = HTTPData```. Please take a look at [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)